# How can I create an ad-hoc network in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking

I know the iPhone has the ability to connect to an ad-hoc network; can it create one?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry - the iPhone (and iPad) are not able to create networks.

Comment: Do you know why they would create this restriction?

Comment: For both security and battery life.  There is a secondary solution coming in iOS7, can't talk about because of NDA...